# The site return "The server returned a '500 Internal Server Error'."

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I thing that the problem is in the database config, but I can't find it.

Here have response from database and not working: http://pirintourist.coxslot.com/web/

Here no have connection with database and work: http://pirintourist.coxslot.com/web/login

In my parameters.yml have this:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: mysql.2freehosting.com
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: tourist
    database_user: tourist
    database_password: ********
```

Comment: Your server isn't responding anymore... What's the error when you try in dev, not in prod?

Comment: Check the `app/logs/prod.log`. Given the `HTTP500` you should have a one or more lines marked as `CRITICAL`. That should give you a hint...

Comment: And BTW, since you writed your credentials in plain text here, change them as quick as possible... Even if your post has been edited since, they were visible.